# Rails + REGEX: Extract name from email domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-4, gsub

I'm creating a new record in Company table based on the logic below:

```
if company.nil?
  Company.create!(name: User.get_company_name(self.email)), domain: User.get_domain(self.email))
end
```

I want to extract the name of the domain to place in the Company table. Ie. If I have nick@nike.com, I want to use regular expressions to substitute in `'Nike'` as the company name. Or, in the case of ryan@ryandrake.com, I'd want the company name to be `'Ryandrake'`.

I already have this method I am using to extract the domain, but haven't managed to edit it to extract the name:

```
def self.get_domain(email_address)
  email_address.gsub(/.+@([^.]+.+)/, '\1') // Returns 'nike.com' or 'ryandrake.com'
end
```

Any help with modifying the method above to just return `'Nike'` or `'Ryandrake'` would be super helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do just `email_address[/(?<=@)[^.]+/]` to get the desired name.

```
def self.get_domain(email_address)
  email_address[/(?<=@)[^.]+/]
end
```

***Example:***

```
"pavan@gmail.com"[/(?<=@)[^.]+/]
 => "gmail"
```

[**DEMO**](http://rubular.com/r/XTVsYvIOBV)

Comment: Thanks Pavan! This is the simplest and most elegant solution I was after.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex to capture the letters between `@` and `.` : `(?<=@)(.*)(?=\.)`
and then replace with whole string.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lW4oV0/1)

or

`gsub(/.+(?<=@)(.*)(?=\.).+/, '\1')`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lW4oV0/2)

Answer (score 0):

Put the capturing group only to capture the word chars present next to `@`. `.+` inside the capturing group helps to capture also the `.com` part also.

```
email_address.gsub(/.+@([^.]+).+/, '\1')
```

or

```
email_address.gsub(/.+@([^.]+)\..+/, '\1')
```